# What does fileTransformOperation from File Operations do?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I was looking for a move operation available for Jenkins in documentation for [File Operations Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/). I stumbled upon `fileTransformOperation`, wondering if I could use it. However the information on this is very sparse.

This operation has two arguments: `includes` and `excludes`. You are supposed to specify the pattern for which files to *copy*. However there is no `destination` argument. So where are they copied then? Apart from this `fileCopyOperation` already exists and serves this purpose.